# Using an assigned variable to loop entry to class module

Tags: vba, excel, class, variables

I'm trying to loop through a list of employees and add them to a class module. My roadblock is to figure out how to use a declared variable used in a for loop as an instance for the class.

Basically, I want to use `nameValue`, where `employee` is, as a `New EmployeeClass`.

The idea is using a string value of the employee in the current iteration to populate the class, rather than having to manually dim/set.

Would Appreciate any help!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Vacation()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim rowNum As Integer: rowNum = 5
   Dim colNum As Integer: colNum = 4
   Dim Vac As Integer: Vac = 46
   Dim obj, obj1 As Range
   Dim onePersonLoop As Range
   Dim nameLocation As Range
   Dim vacLocation As Range
   Dim emp_vacDates As Range

   For i = 2 To 2
      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

           Set onePersonLoop = .Cells(rowNum,_ 
                   colNum).Offset(-1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, -2)


           For rowNum = 5 To 359 Step 6

               Dim emps As Collection
               Set emps = New Collection
               Set nameLocation = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-1,_                                                 
                -1).EntireRow.Cells(1, 2)
               Dim nameValue As String
               nameValue = nameLocation.Value

              Dim employee As EmployeeClass
              Set employee = New EmployeeClass                        
              emps.Add employee

           Next rowNum

       End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

**Class Module:**

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim vName As String
 Dim newCollection As Collection

 Public Property Get Name() As String
   Name = vName
 End Property

 Public Property Let Name(nme As String)
   vName = nme
   newCollection.Add nme

 End Property


 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set newCollection = New Collection
   vName = ""
 End Sub

 Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set newCollection = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could remove the ">" from your code.   You're creating a new collection each time through the loop, so it will only ever contain one employee.  Your class is difficult to follow - what's the function of the Collection there?  Is the class supposed to represent a single employee?  `Dim rowNum As Integer: rowNum = 5` is better written as `Const rowNum As Long = 5` (always safer to use Long and there's no advantage to using the smaller Integer type)

Comment: My idea was to create a class for employees (1 class to store every person). I eventually want to create a bigger class to store sub-classes, such as employee.

Comment: I would start with an "employee" class first - it will be much easier to deal with, and you can just add instances of that class to a Collection until you create the "employees" class.

Comment: I am with the helpers above.  Create one collection for employee class and add to the collection if the employee is not present.  If you will ever need to change the values of the class instance, then a Dictionary is more appropriate as a container.

Comment: as far as the looping. use "For each" in both the collection or dictionary implementation.

Comment: OK, I have moved the creation of collection outside the loop, so it's only created once; and omitted the collection in the class module.  As far as the "For each" suggestion, my issue is that I use the for loop with a step to go through the employee list (Not referencing every row). This is why I wanted to have a variable that sets the cell that contains the name of the employee, rather than manually entering in employee instances. (Dim employee1, employee2, ... As EmployeeClass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your code which I think addresses your core question.

I'm not following your sheet layout: this just picks up 10 employee names from A1:A10 -

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim emps As New Collection
    Dim emp As employee
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
        Set emp = New employee
        emp.Name = c.Value
        emps.Add emp
    Next c

    For Each emp In emps
        Debug.Print emp.Name
    Next emp

End Sub
```

Employee class:

```
Option Explicit

Dim vName As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
  Name = vName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(nme As String)
  vName = nme
End Property
```